# Check dynamic value for field in struct in go using testify

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, testify

I have a `user service` that validates the user data and formats it and then calls Firebase service which creates a firebase user and return firebase id and then it pass that user data to `repository` layer. My user struct has an `ID` field is populated by `uuid` in `user service`  before passing to `repository` layer. I am mocking the firebase service and repository layer using `strecher/testify`. But the test is failing since the `ID` is populated by service layer and I cannot pass the `ID` to the user data used by mock function.

```
user := model.User{
        ID:         "",
        FirebaseID: "",
        FirstName: "Test",
        LastName:  "User",
        FullName:  "Test User",
        Email:     "testuser@email.com"
        Password: "password",
    }
```

Service layer code

```
func (u userService) CreateUser(user model.User) error {
  err := validateFields(user)
  if err != nil {
      return fmt.Errorf("userService CreateUser: %w", err)
  }

  user.FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName
  user.FirebaseID, err = u.authClient.CreateUser(user)
  if err != nil {
      return fmt.Errorf("userService CreateUser: %w", err)
  }

  user.ID = uuid.NewString()
  err = u.userRepo.CreateUser(user)
  if err != nil {
      return fmt.Errorf("userService CreateUser: %w", err)
  }

return nil
```

}

Test code

```
func TestCreateUser(t *testing.T) {
  mockFirebaseAuthClient := new(MockFirebaseAuthClient)
  mockPostgresRepo := new(MockPostgresRepo)
  userService := NewUserService(mockPostgresRepo, mockFirebaseAuthClient)

  t.Run("Valid data", func(t *testing.T) {
      user := model.User{
        ID:         "",
        FirebaseID: "firebaseuniqueid",
        FirstName: "Test",
        LastName:  "User",
        FullName:  "Test User",
        Email:     "testuser@email.com",
        Password: "password",
      }
      mockFirebaseAuthClient.On("CreateUser", user).Return("firebaseuniqueid", nil)
      mockPostgresRepo.On("CreateUser", user).Return(nil)
      err := userService.CreateUser(user)
      if err != nil {
          t.Fatalf("Expectd: nil, got: %v", err)
      }
})
```

Error while testing

```
mock: Unexpected Method Call
-----------------------------

CreateUser(model.User)
        0: model.User{ID:"f87fd2f3-5801-4359-a565-a4eb13a6de37", FirebaseID:"firebaseuniqueid", FirstName:"Test", LastName:"User", FullName:"Test User", Email:"testuser@email.com", Password:"password"}

The closest call I have is: 

CreateUser(model.User)
        0: model.User{ID:"", FirebaseID:"firebaseuniqueid", FirstName:"Test", LastName:"User", FullName:"Test User", Email:"testuser@email.com", Password:"password"}

Difference found in argument 0:

--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 (model.User) {
- ID: (string) "",
+ ID: (string) (len=36) "f87fd2f3-5801-4359-a565-a4eb13a6de37",
  FirebaseID: (string) (len=16) "firebaseuniqueid",

Diff: 0: FAIL:  (model.User={f87fd2f3-5801-4359-a565-a4eb13a6de37 firebaseuniqueid Test User Test User testuser@email.com  password}) != (model.User={ firebaseuniqueid Test User Test User testuser@email.com  password}) [recovered]
```

Is there any way I could check the dynamically created uuid or ignore the values in the struct in the test?

Comment: You can mock the `uuid.NewString()` implementation to return the expected UUID, or perhaps use the [MatchedBy](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.7.0/mock#MatchedBy) to assert a valid UUID is set on your user model?

Comment: Since `uuid` is not injected into the service layer, how can it be mocked? It is an imported package.

Comment: Added an answer to your question in this comment @amljs :) can also be used as a solution to the question. Let me know if it doesn't work :)

Comment: @Wolfgang Your answer works fine for checking both UUIDs. But it modifies the method signature which I don't want.  What I wanted is either compare the UUIDs or ignore them. So I used `mock.Anything` to ignore the argument. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't want to consider `mockFirebaseAuthClient.On("CreateUser", user).Return("firebaseuniqueid", nil)` and `mockPostgresRepo.On("CreateUser", user).Return(nil)` and just want to mock that calls, then you can use `mock.Anything` as the argument in both the calls instead of `user` like this `mockFirebaseAuthClient.On("CreateUser", mock.Anything).Return("firebaseuniqueid", nil)` . So the arguments will not be considerd and the mock calls will return required value.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question of

> Since uuid is not injected into the service layer, how can it be mocked? It is an imported package.

Like this, first, define an interface with the same method we want to mock

```
type uuidGen interface {
    String() string
}
```

Then, define a mock type in which we're going to define our method

```
type mockGen struct{}
```

Then, define the method on the type

```
func (u *mockGen) String() string {
    return "test"
}
```

Update `CreateUser` function to receive a `uuidGen` parameter that shares the method `String()` with `uuid`'s package.

```
func (u userService) CreateUser(uuid uuidGen, user User) error {
    err := validateFields(user)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("userService CreateUser: %w", err)
    }
    user.FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName
    user.FirebaseID, err = u.authClient.CreateUser(user)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("authClient CreateUser: %w", err)
    }
    user.ID = uuid.String()
    err = u.userRepo.CreateUser(user)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("userService CreateUser: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now we can write the test like this, see how the 2 methods accept different types that implement the interface `uuidGen` and can call a method `String()`

```
func TestCreateUser(t *testing.T) {
    mockFirebaseAuthClient := new(MockFirebaseAuthClient)
    mockPostgresRepo := new(MockPostgresRepo)
    userService := NewUserService("test", "test")

    t.Run("Valid data", func(t *testing.T) {
            user := User{
                    ID:         "",
                    FirebaseID: "firebaseuniqueid",
                    FirstName:  "Test",
                    LastName:   "User",
                    FullName:   "Test User",
                    Email:      "testuser@email.com",
                    Password:   "password",
            }
            mockFirebaseAuthClient.On("CreateUser", user).Return("firebaseuniqueid", nil)
            mockPostgresRepo.On("CreateUser", user).Return(nil)
            gen := new(mockGen)
            err := userService.CreateUser(gen, user)
            if err != nil {
                    t.Fatalf("Expectd: nil, got: %v", err)
            }
            realUUID := uuid.New()
            err = userService.CreateUser(realUUID, user)
            if err != nil {
                    t.Fatalf("Expectd: nil, got: %v", err)
            }
            t.Log("Mock UUID:", gen.String())  // prints test
            t.Log("Real UUID UUID:", realUUID.String()) // prints a UUID
    })
}
```

Run it with `go test -v` to see the output of `t.Log(...)`